# Set file size range using Imagick in PHP

Tags: php, imagick

I'm very new to `Imagick`, less than 24 hours.

So I'm trying to figure a way, if possible, to set the file size of an image to be within a certain range

In my case, I want the image size to be between 100KB and 300KB

I read about the Imagick `extent` to set the maximum file size of an image

```
$imagick->setOption('jpeg:extent', '300kb')
```

I tried it with an image of 1.5MB but the result was 321KB which is over 300KB

I also read about the `Imagick::setCompressionQuality()` but it think I can't be able to set the file size with it or rather if there's any calculation to be made to attain this goal.

I want to know if I can compress an image to be between a range of file size

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly set the file size of an image using `Imagick`. However, you can use `compression` methods to reduce the file size of the image until it reaches your desired size.